# Pushing/Creating elements dynamically in jQuery and then immediately looping through to append HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, dynamically-generated

I'm trying to define an area in a jQuery snippet that is easy for a user to alter. The end goal is the user defines the values, but the jQuery will create the objects from the list.

I start with this simple HTML div:

```
<div class="slider-container"></div>
```

Followed by the js concept:

```
var newSlides = [];
$(".slider-container").each(function(){
    newSlides.push({
        image: {
            url:       "http://placekitten.com/960/400",
            title:     "Sample Title 1",
            subtitle:  "Sample Subtitle 1"
        },
        image: {
            url:       "http://placekitten.com/961/401",
            title:     "Sample title 2" 
        };
    });
});
```

I would like it to be able to then take these values and do something like:

```
var index = 1;
$("slider-container").append(
    $("<div/>", {class: "slide s-" + index++})
        .append($("<img/>, {src: "url-from-above"}))
        .append($("<div/>, {class: "slide-titles"})
            .append($("<h2/>, {class: "title").text("text-from-above))
            .append($("<h3/>, {class: "subtitle").text("text-from-above))))
```

So that the final result would be:

```
<div class="slider-container">
    <div class="slide s-1">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/960/400 />
        <div class="slide-titles">
            <h2>Sample Title 1</h2>
            <h3>Sample Subtitle 1</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide s-2">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/961/401" />
        <div class="slide-titles">
            <h2>Sample Title 2</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The goal being a user just has to define values and not have to worry about defining the HTML or putting things in the correct places. Easy to edit for anyone.

Comment: So what is the question then?

Comment: I would consider using some type of templating engine.

Comment: e.g. http://handlebarsjs.com/ or http://mustache.github.io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with others that a templating engine like Mustache would be useful.  If you just want to do it with straight jQuery though:

```
for(i=0; i<newSlides.length; i++) {
    var slider = $('.slider-container');
    var slide_data = newSlides[i];
    var slide = $('<div class="slide s-' + i + '"/>').appendTo(slider);
    $('<img src="' + slide_data.url + '" />').appendTo(slide);
    var titles = $('<div class="slide-titles"/>').appendTo(slide);
    if(slide_data.title) {
        $('<h2>' + slide_data.title + '</h2>').appendTo(titles);
    }
    if(slide_data.subtitle) {
        $('<h3>' + slide_data.subtitle + '</h3>').appendTo(titles);
    }
}
```

For the code above, you'll need to modify your `push()` statement so that it pushes the objects into the array directly instead of pushing an object comprised of your target objects. E.g.

```
var newSlides = [];
newSlides.push(
    {
        url:       "http://placekitten.com/960/400",
        title:     "Sample Title 1",
        subtitle:  "Sample Subtitle 1"
    },
    {
        url:       "http://placekitten.com/961/401",
        title:     "Sample title 2" 
    }
);
```

Comment: Perfect. The reason I can't use a templating engine at the moment is I'm tasked with making it as lightweight as possible with ease of implementing it in several different projects. So this is great imo. Thanks.

Comment: @o_O The doT.js template engine is just slightly over 100 lines of code, uncompressed.  A template engine is not an expensive proposition.